# Can the "Recent Posts Widget with Thumbnails" plugin in WordPress link to external URLs?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, widget

I am creating a WordPress site which has a menu on the home page, which was created with the plugin mentioned above. This menu is comprised of posts from my site, which should each link to an external URL.

The problem I'm having is that when I click on the post in the menu, it redirects me to the WordPress permalink, instead of the external URL I set for the post. Clicking on the posts on any other part of the site takes me to the external link, as I expected.

Any help would be much appreciated!

The plugin I am using: https://wordpress.org/plugins/recent-posts-widget-with-thumbnails/

Comment: How do you define that external link?

Comment: I'm using the Themify Magazine theme, and one of the options is it lets you add an external link to a post, so when you click it, it redirects there, instead of the page on your site.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that "Recent Posts Widget With Thumbnails" doesn't provide any way to overload the template used to display the widget. The permalink is displayed in `includes/widget.php` template (not overridable) on line 20:

```
?>><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"<?php echo $link_target; ?>><?php
```

You have two options here:

1. Change that line to display the meta used by Themify to display the external link. This is not recommended because you won't be able to update the plugin (or if you do, it will break your modification) and this could end in a a possible security issue.
2. Just do what the plugin does yourself. It's not that difficult.

You'll just have to edit your home page template (front-page.php or index.php, depending of how you set Wordpress about this), and use [`get_posts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) to query the last posts:

```
$last_posts = get_posts('posts_per_page=5');
```

And display them using [`the_post_thumbnail`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_post_thumbnail/) for the thumbnails. You can use the template from the plugin and change it to your need.